# Upgrading SQL/TFS OS from 2003 Std to 2008 Enterprise - Is it safe?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008

We have a server running 2003 standard edition currently running :

- SQL Server Standard Edition
- Team Foundation Server 2005

We want to upgrade the OS to 2008 Enterprise edition.

1. Can I upgrade or will I need a complete re-install.
2. If its an upgrade, are there any issues that I should be aware of, like is this going to cause issues with TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time a go we ran were upgrading a few of our servers from 2003 to 2008. We ran into a few problems with our programs not working properly after the upgrade was finished (SQL was one of them). Fortunately, we were in a situation where we had the time to simply format the servers and start with a fresh install. I don't have any specifics as to what went wrong because of this but I can at least offer some advice:

1. BACKUPS!! Make sure you have your current servers backed up as well as all of your SQL files.
2. Make sure those backups work!
3. Test it out. We weren't lucky enough to have a test environment for this, but if you have one use it.
4. Make sure you know the software. A lot of times people will have to upgrade a server but may not be knowledgeable with the software on it. Having someone good with the software can save time in troubleshooting if there are any issues.
5. Consider your time factors. What will take longer, doing an upgrade and possibly having to troubleshoot or starting fresh and installing everything?

My advice would be to start fresh. It's what worked the best for us but maybe you'll have more luck.

Answer (score 3):

Can you tell me why you are upgrading?   We have TFS on a 2003 box and i don't really see a need at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look (search) through MSDN and MSDN blogs. Most of the scenarios are covered once you can the information.

(I know SQL Server 2003 --> 2008 has been covered as this is a pre-requisite for TFS 2010.)

Comment: He asked about the OS, not SQL version.

Comment: That was an example of coverage, not the only coverage.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded Server 2003 to Server 2008 "in place". It is running SQL Server 2005 and has continued to do so without any problems. However, I then promoted it (temporarily) to a DC which screws up the SQL Server group security so just be wary about that (the fix is supposedly here although I haven't had time to try it out yet: [SQL Server 2005 on 2008 DC - Cannot change service user](https://serverfault.com/questions/24484/sql-server-2005-on-2008-dc-cannot-change-service-user) )